# Are there any fully analytically solvable nonlinear oscillators?

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators

I'm trying to find a simple one-dimensional problem, in which a particle would oscillate with some energy, and the period of oscillation would depend on particle energy (unlike in harmonic oscillator). I could take any potential, different from parabolic, and be done, but all such potentials appear to not lead to explicit closed form solutions.

I've tried various $x^\alpha$ potentials, tried radial Kepler effective potential $K/r^2-Q/r$, some others, but all they appear to give $t(x)$ instead of explicit $x(t)$ as closed forms.

Another way might be to use potential $\propto|x|$, and consider it piecewise, but the solution quickly becomes quite ugly and requires using such functions as $\min$, $\max$ etc., cluttering the final expression a lot.

So my question is: are there any shapes of potential, for which equation of motion would be solvable in simple explicit closed form $x(t)$, and at the same time period would depend on energy?

Comment: I would start with integrable models https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrable_models. If a system is not integrable it does not have a closed analytical solution, for sure, however what you consider "fully analytically solvable" probably depends on your comfort level with analytical functions that go beyond the usual set of "exp, sine and cosine", of which there are dozens of major types and hundreds of sub-cases which are discussed in advanced mathematical formula tables and handbooks. Generally speaking these advanced functions are considered "analytical".

Comment: I don't believe any nonlinear oscillator has an exact solution. Even the simple Duffing oscillator requires expansion to a Taylor's series to obtain an approximate analytical solution. Poincare may have provided a theorem that exclude tractability from such systems.

Comment: BTW very good question

Comment: @docscience This is matter of taste, but the definition of "exact solution" you're using seems unduly restrictive to me.  I (and I think many physicists) don't have much of a problem calling solutions written in terms of, say, "special" functions (like elliptic functions) exact since they are, well, "exact" solutions in the sense that they give the solution to arbitrarily high precision, just like if the solution were written in terms of "elementary" functions.

Comment: I'd approach this by more clearly defining the available solution set. Then just choose a solution $x(t)$ and determine the force implied by it, i.e. the second derivative with respect to $t$. You are then left with a force field and want to find the potential - i.e. integral with respect to $x$. I'm guessing that mostly this will not admit a closed solution, but hey, you've turned the problem around somewhat!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the [pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)) would be an interesting example. The equation of motion of an ideal pendulum of length $\ell$ in a uniform gravity field is

$${d^2\theta\over dt^2}+{g\over \ell} \sin\theta=0$$

It is well known that in the small angle approximation this reduces to a harmonic oscillator, but the precise solution involves elliptic integrals, and can be expressed in the inverses of such integrals, which are called [elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function). This class of functions was an object of intense study in the 19th century, and several special forms got specific names. In particular, the pendulum can be solved in terms of a [Jacobi elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions).

Comment: This is a good suggestion, as it admits an expression for the period in terms of elliptic integrals, but does _not_ provide $\theta(t)$: "there is no solution that can be written in terms of elementary functions" (wikipedia).  I think this is what the asker is looking for.

Comment: @anon0909: there is very little useful information to be had from the restriction to "elementary functions" or, if you want to be even more restrictive e.g. polynomials. The mathematically and physically useful classification is in terms of constants of motion, which still includes systems that have solutions which can not be expressed with elementary functions, alone.

Comment: @anon0909 Moreover, the set of twelve Jacobi elliptic functions can be described as the unique doubly periodic functions with first order poles in their unit cells (there has to be some kind of singularity there, otherwise, by Liouville's Theorem, *i.e.* every bounded entire function is constant, not the L theorem of Hamiltonian mechanics, our function is constant). Elliptic functions follow fully from intuitive, geometrical axioms and you can reason a great deal about their behavior from first principles, without reference to series or anything else. See the Wiki page ....

Comment: @anon0909  .... [Jacobi Elliptic Functions: Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Introduction): That makes them much more intuitive than may "elementary" functions. Another way to construct them is simply through the Weierstrass Elliptic function, you sum up an infinite series with terms of the form $(z-n\,\omega_1 - m\,\omega_2)^{-2}$, reasoning this series is doubly periodic, by construction, and is the "simplest" because the terms need to decay like $O(n^{-2})$ for convergence. Then define *all* elliptic functions in terms of this one and a classication ...

Comment: @anon0909 ... of all the possible topologies of the functions' Riemann surfaces to find all possible doubly periodic functions. Stillwell gives a lovely walkthrough of this approach in his "Geometry of Surfaces".

Comment: @anon0909 actualy, there's a solution which can be written in terms of special functions, namely [Jacobi amplitude $\operatorname{am}(x,k)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question depends an awful lot on what you mean by "closed form" solutions.

Consider the standard harmonic oscillator where the solution is
$$x(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \phi) \, .$$
In what sense, if any, is this a "closed form"?
That $\cos$ function is defined in terms of a power series
$$\cos(x) \equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \, .$$
Lots of differential equations can be solved with power series methods, and in cases where the solved equation is important those power series solutions tend to get Fancy Names$^{\text{TM}}$ like ["Bessel functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), ["Jocobi elliptic functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions) (see doetoe's answer), etc.
Those other special functions aren't really any less elementary than $\sin$ and $\cos$: they have recurrence relations, completeness/orthogonality relations, and reasonably simple transformation under derivatives, etc.

You can also always use [harmonic balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_balance) to write the (homogeneous) solution of an oscillator in terms of a Fourier series.

**Aside:**

The reason $\sin$ and $\cos$ are preferred is that they form a closed basis under time translation:
$$\cos(t + \delta t) = A \cos(t) - B \sin(t)$$
where $A = \cos(\delta t)$ and $B = \sin(\delta t)$.
This makes them nice in systems where the equations of motion themselves are time translation invariant because all time derivatives turn $\cos$ and $\sin$ into each other.